# Is there a way to update application created with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, cx-freeze, python-packaging

I have created and distributed a msi file using `cx_freeze` for my python project. I have made some changes in the project, let's say *v2.0*. Is there anyway I can update the app in my client computer without having to send the msi again ?

Or is there any other packaging library I can use which will let me do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSI Upgrade Code for upgrading your application. Check out [Create an upgradeable msi file with cx_Freeze](https://linuxtut.com/en/f86fee79e75e37e62b74/) for reference.

First, you need to create a UUID (GUID) for the Upgrade Code:

```
import uuid str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'appname.orgname.org')).upper()
```

You just have to replace'appname.orgname.org' with an appropriate one.

Next, prepare `setup.py`.

```
#Application information
name = 'memopad'
version = '1.0.0'
author = 'example'
author_email = 'sample@example.xxx'
url = 'http://example.xxx'
description = 'Text Editor'

#Specify the GUID here (basically it should not be changed)
upgrade_code = '{3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301}'
#For 64-bit Windows, switch the installation folder
# ProgramFiles(64)Folder seems to be replaced with the actual directory on the msi side
programfiles_dir = 'ProgramFiles64Folder' if distutils.util.get_platform() == 'win-amd64' else 'ProgramFilesFolder'

#Options to use with the build command on Windows
build_exe_options = {
    'packages': ['os'],
    'excludes': ['tkinter'], #Exclude tkinter as it is not used
    'includes': ['PySide.QtCore', 'PySide.QtGui', 'gui', 'commands'],
    'include_files': ['img/', 'lang/', 'license/'],
    'include_msvcr': True, #Since it uses PySide, it cannot be started unless Microsoft's C runtime is included.
    'compressed'   : True
}

# bdist_Options to use with the msi command
bdist_msi_options = {
    'upgrade_code': upgrade_code,
    'add_to_path': False,
    'initial_target_dir': '[%s]\%s\%s' % (programfiles_dir, author, name)
}

options = {
    'build_exe': build_exe_options,
    'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options
}

#exe information
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform == 'win32' else None
icon = 'img/app_icon.ico'

mainexe = Executable(
    'main.py',
    targetName = 'Memopad.exe',
    base = base,
    icon = icon,
    copyDependentFiles = True
)

setup(
    name=name,
    version=version,
    author=author,
    author_email=author_email,
    url=url,
    description=description,
    options=options,
    executables=[mainexe]
)
```

Please note that if you change the UpgradeCode, it will not be considered as the same package and you will not be able to manage the package properly.

Comment: Ok. But now how do I push my changes to the client ?